# Maven profile exclude file unless another profile is also supplied

Tags: maven

We have a maven profile configuration to exclude some development files from the final package, simple enough:

```
<profile>
    <id>production</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/DevAccessConfig.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>application-dev.properties</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/DevFileClient.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

We want to define a new profile (or a new build property), say `k8s` that would include the last file, `DevFileClient.*`, back again in the jar file, but still excluding the first two. So when we run one of the following commands, only the first two files are excluded.

```
mvn clean package -Pproduction,k8s
```

**OR**

```
mvn clean package -Pproduction -Dk8s=true
```

Comment: Put those `DevAccessConfig`into a separate modules which will not being included in the final package... The property is a question why is even a property file available for local dev (maybe neccessary during running of tests that would mean to put them into `src/test/resources`... And why do you need those those things `DevAccessConfig*`and `DevFileClient.*`??

Comment: They are being used while launching the application locally instead of deploying to a cluster. Now we have an intermediate deployment option, which would still require first two to be absent. A new module may work with some additional runtime settings to exclude the first two though.

Comment: If you really deploying it into a cluster you should not put any environment specifc configuration in your app (12-factor app!! https://12factor.net/) ... And what kind of intermediate deployment option? Why is there code changes needed ? Sounds like a bad design?